# How to detect if any variable is not empty in a set of variables

Tags: php, validation, if-statement, is-empty

I want to make sure that at least one field is filled before sending a form. How do i validate this in PHP?

```
if ($A == '' || $B == ''){
echo 'Fill a minimum of one';
}
```

But this requires that all A and B not to be empty. 
How do i do this?

Comment: I'd recommend you check out Laravel.

Comment: Umm shouldn't you be using the `&&` operator? Because it's like -> _if both my variables are empty, fill at least one_. Right now you are doing -> _if any of my variables are empty, fill any one_ which is logically wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of the comma seperator and `isset()` for checking multiple variables..

```
if(!isset($a,$b))
{
 echo 'Fill a minimum of one';
}
```

However, `empty()` cannot do a check for multiple variables.. You need to do them individually like this..

```
if(empty($a) || empty($b))
{
    echo 'Fill a minimum of one';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the equality operator, meaning you want at least one to be empty.

Replace with the inequality operator if you want to check if at least one is different from "" (empty).

```
if ($A != '' || $B != '')
{
    echo 'Fill a minimum of one';
}
```

By the way, you are talking about variable emptiness. Maybe you should also consider using the [empty](http://www.php.net/empty) function to check whether a variable is empty or not.